# Beginner trouble with Haskell syntax

Tags: haskell, syntax, parse-error

So I've only used Haskell for simple tutorials so far, and the below code is giving me a "parse error"...I know it's something to do with my syntax but I've no idea what

```
 --ternarySearch
  7 ternarySearch :: (Float -> Float) -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
  8 ternarySearch f a b tau = do 
  9                         if (abs(b-a) < tau)
 10                           then return ((a+b)/2)
 11                         c = (a + (b-a)/3)
 12                         d = (b - (b-a)/3)
 13                         if f(c) < f(d)
 14                           then return (ternarySearch f c b tau)
 15                         else return (ternarySearch f a d tau)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ternary.hs:11:25: parse error on input `c'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are doing lots of things wrong: do-notation without using Monad, Indendation, if/else is wrong. I would suggest you to learn Haskell using any tutorial/book before trying out programs in it.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately this is one of my first forays into the language. For starters: what should indentation be like? It's certainly one of the main issues giving me trouble.

Comment: nvm I think I've got the indentaion, but my main problem remains the same: what's causing the parse error?

Comment: Lack of `else`. In most other languages, `else` is optional. In Haskell, `if` is more akin to `?:` than `if` in other languages: `if x then y` is like writing `x ? y` in C, and will give you an error for the same reasons: it is an expression, and it can't not evaluate to something when the condition is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing lots of things wrong:

- You should not use do-notation unless the context is a `Monad`.
- Misuse of `return`: I think you are confusing imperative lanaguages `return` with Haskell's one.
- if/else usage: Note that in Haskell if-else is an expression. So both if and else are mandatory as opposed to certain other languages.
- Indendation seems to be wrong: See the [rules here.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation)

A better version of what you are trying to do using guards:

```
ternarySearch :: (Float -> Float) -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
ternarySearch f a b tau 
    | abs (b-a) < tau = (a+b) / 2
    | f c < f d = ternarySearch f c b tau
    | otherwise = ternarySearch f a d tau
    where
      c = a + (b-a)/3
      d = b - (b-a)/3
```

That being said, I would suggest you to read some [book](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) to get a better understanding.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help (and the patience).

I actually already began to make the "where" change at the end there and you're definitely right in that I was thinking of the imperative "return"